# Run Linux server from virtual box seamlessly

Tags: linux, xampp, debian, virtualbox

My LAMPP server runs on a debian linux OS which is hosted on Oracle Virtual Box. To start the lampp server on mwindows XP PC, I have to:

1. Open Virtual Box
2. Start Debian Linux
3. Open Linux Terminal
4. Run LAMPP start command.

Is there any way to automate this process or reduce the number of steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a .bat file to use vboxmanage to start a vm

https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-startvm

Then set the debian vm up to run your LAMPP start command on boot using sysv

http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/28